# Selecting from two queries select not null

Tags: sql, oracle, null, subquery

i have query that the result is a single value there are many cases that bring me a null value in this case that's what i not need so i need make another query to bring me back a value, so i need to make a one query that bring me back when is null value in the first query omit the result and execute the second query.

the firts query is

```
SELECT DISTINCT
           FIRST_VALUE (pac1.pac_name)
              OVER (ORDER BY pac1.pac_final_date DESC)
      FROM    matricula mac
           INNER JOIN
              periodo pac1
           ON mac.pac_id = pac1.pac_id
     WHERE mac.ent_id = 26172 AND mac.mac_estado IN (8072, 10221)
```

the second query is

```
SELECT DISTINCT
              FIRST_VALUE (pac1.pac_name)
                 OVER (ORDER BY pac1.pac_final_date DESC)
         FROM  registro rea
              INNER JOIN
                 periodo pac1
              ON rea.pac_id = pac1.pac_id
        WHERE rea.ent_id = 26172
```

The two queries bring me back the same value, but first i need to consult for the first query, there are two cases.

case -1 --> when execute query#1 and bring me the result

Result

```
FIRST_VALUE (pac1.pac_name)
--------------------------
|Oct/2012 - Feb/2013     |
--------------------------
```

case -2 --> when execute query#1 the result is  `null`, then execute a query #2 that will assure bring me a value

Result

```
FIRST_VALUE (pac1.pac_name)
--------------------------
|Oct/2012 - Feb/2013     |
--------------------------
```

This is probably an easy question, but any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please provide some sample data and the desired result.

Comment: Do not post your clarifications in comments. Use [Edit] instead.

Comment: I asked for sample **data** in table format and the result as a table as well.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "_SQL_" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Comment: I need a query to execute oracle client  the DBMS is Oracle

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COALESCE(

    (SELECT DISTINCT
            FIRST_VALUE (pac1.pac_name)
               OVER (ORDER BY pac1.pac_final_date DESC)
        FROM    matricula mac
            INNER JOIN
               periodo pac1
            ON mac.pac_id = pac1.pac_id
        WHERE mac.ent_id = 26172 AND mac.mac_estado IN (8072, 10221) )

    ,(SELECT DISTINCT
              FIRST_VALUE (pac1.pac_name)
                 OVER (ORDER BY pac1.pac_final_date DESC)
         FROM  registro rea
              INNER JOIN
                 periodo pac1
              ON rea.pac_id = pac1.pac_id
        WHERE rea.ent_id = 26172))
```

I am not positive without test data and a few more things but you could also use periodio as the main table and then LEFT OUTER JOIN to the other 2 tables.  Use a case expression to determine which table/rows to use first in your order by.  a similar method with EXISTS could also probably be considered:

```
SELECT DISTINCT FIRST_VALUE(pac1.pac_name) OVER (ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN mac.pac_id IS NOT NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, pac1.pac_final_date DESC)
FROM
    periodo pac1
    LEFT JOIN matricula mac
    ON pac1.pac_id = mac.pac_id
    AND mac.ent_id = 26172
    AND mac.mac_estado IN (8072, 10221)
    LEFT JOIN registro rea
    ON pac1.pac_id = rea.pac_id
    AND rea.ent_id = 26172
```

Comment: if you see in the two queries that i use in the statement `FROM` they have different tables

Comment: @ByronFigueroa so I edited an answer to show you how you can use COALESCE and sub queries.  Depending on relationships of and a few other things you can still do this in another query.  And actually now that I look at queries yet again you could use periodo as the main table conditional left outer joins to both other tables and still pull it off in 1 query